# C++ What is wrong with this version of the quadratic formula?

Tags: c++

In my book, it asks me the following question  This is for compsci-1

What is wrong with this version of the quadratic formula?

```
x1 = (-b - sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a; 
x2 = (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a;
```

Comment: You just mentioned the formulae but what is the actual issue? Are you getting any compilation error?

Comment: You need brackets... `x1 = (-b - sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);` and also some reading on precedence and associativity.

Comment: No, This was the question that was asked in the book which I need to as exercises. The teacher asked us for .cpp file and screenshot of it.

Comment: Then really read about precedence and associativity and go through some simple examples of it. These are basic things you need to understand. This is not even complex, as soon as you understand some simple examples you'll see it clearly.

Comment: If you ever studied algebra, you should also understand the idea of complex roots.  How would you handle that situation?

Comment: Also, the textbook formula may not play well with certain input.  [See the discussion here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866331/numerically-stable-algorithm-for-solving-the-quadratic-equation-when-a-is-very)

Comment: `x/y*a` is `(x/y)*a`; to get the `a` into the denominator you need to write it as `x/(y*a)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation your code is translating is:

[image: wrong quadratic formula]

which of course is not the solution for quadratic equations. You want a solution for this equation:

[image: correct quadratic formula]

What's the difference? In the first one you compute the numerator, then you divide by two, then you multiply by a. That's what your code is doing. In the second one you compute the numerator, then you compute the denominator, finally you divide them.

So with additional variables:

```
num1 = -b - sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c);
num2 = -b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c);
den = 2 * a;

x1 = num1 / den;
x2 = num2 / den;
```

which can of course be written as:

```
x1 = (-b - sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
x2 = (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
```

Where you have to plug in those parenthesis in order to force the denominator to be computed before the division. As suggested in the comment by @atru.